# Busca em matriz Javascript

Tags: javascript, array, matriz, algoritmo-de-busca

Boa tarde.

Peço a gentileza de me auxiliarem num problema simples (pra vocês kkk), mas que está me incomodando.

Tenho uma matriz fixa (valores são retirados de um txt)

preciso de uma função de retorne uma outra matriz onde um valor passado por parametro seja igual ao valor da segunda coluna da matriz.

```
function retornaBusca(palavra, matriz){
    let result
    for (i = 0; i < matriz.lenth; i++){
        if( matriz[i][1] == palavra ){
            result.push(matriz[i][0] +'#'+matriz[i][1]
        }
    }
    return result
}
```

Ex:

```
matriz[0][1] = ['josé']        
matriz[1][1] = ['pedro']  
matriz[2][1] = ['joão']  
matriz[3][1] = ['josé']
```

se eu chamasse

```
mat = retornaBusca('josé', matriz)
```

esperava que retornasse

```
mat[0] = 123#josé
mat[1] = 456#josé
```

Muito Obrigado

Comment: Onde esta `let result` faça `let result = [];` e onde está `result.push(matriz[i][0] +'#'+matriz[i][1]` faça `result.push(matriz[i][0] +'#'+matriz[i][1]);`

Answer (score 0):

Senhores, descobri um remendo para resolver meu problema.

o problema se dava em uma linha específica.

`if( matriz[i][1] == palavra )`

essa condição nunca retornava true, mesmo quando os valores correspondia.
meu remendo foi dar um trim() em ambas.

`if( matriz[i][1].trim() == palavra.trim() )`

Obs. antes de chegar a esse remendo, fiz um console.log para ver os resultados.

`console.log( '*' + matriz[i][1] + '*' + palavra + '*')`

o resultado era

`*josé*josé*`

mesmo assim não retornava true. não entendi, mas fica a dica, no meu caso tive que usar o trim()